# How i can calculate the Macaulay Duration without knowing the price of the bond?

Tags: finance

For an annual bond with coupons $c =40$ and 10 years maturity $n=10$ ,face value $P_p=1000$ and interest rate $y = 0.08$ calculate the Macaulay Duration defined as :

$$ D= \frac{1}{P} \left( \frac{ 1\times c}{(1+y)} +\frac{ 2\times c}{(1+y)^2} +\frac{ 3\times c}{(1+y)^3}+ \dots + \frac{ n\times (c+P_p)}{(1+y)^n}   \right) $$

The writer states that the resulted $D =8.1184 $ and the price of the bond $P = 731.5967$.

My question is: How he found these resulted values? First he finds $P$? And how ? What formula he uses ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the price $P$ calculated separately by

$$P = \frac{ c}{(1+y)} +\frac{ c}{(1+y)^2} +\frac{ c}{(1+y)^3}+ \dots + \frac{ c+P_p}{(1+y)^n}$$

? (which I haven't confirmed)

Comment: @peterwhy substituting in the formula in your comment i result to 9.1449.Not the one that the writer states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The price $P$ matches the (unscaled) present values of coupons and the face value, given by:

$$\begin{align*}
P &= \frac{ c}{(1+y)} +\frac{ c}{(1+y)^2} +\frac{ c}{(1+y)^3}+ \dots + \frac{ c+P_p}{(1+y)^n}\\
&= \frac cy \left[1-(1+y)^{-n}\right] + P_p(1+y)^{-n}\\
&= \frac{40}{0.08}\left(1-1.08^{-10}\right) + 1000\cdot 1.08^{-10}\\
&\approx 268.4033 + 463.1935\\
&\approx 731.5967
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you vary much for your answer.It is very useful.